# Removing last marker before creating a new one

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to create a Map with an easy function. Everytime i click, the existing Marker schould be removed and a new one schould appear at click-position.

Creating new ones works fine, but removing them doesn't work. Here the code, I tried:

```
var map;
var latitude, longitude;
var marker;

function placeMarker(location) {

    marker.setMap(null);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: location,
    });
    latitude = location.lat();
    longitude = locaton.lng();

    document.getElementById('koordinaten').innerHTML = '<p>' + latitude + '</p>';

}
```

OK, comment the marker.setMap(null); i can add as much markers as i want, but i want to only have one Marker on the Map.

Can you please help me, how to remove a marker and place a new one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this function the first time, the first line will result in an error, because marker still is `undefined`(doesn't have a `setMap`-method).

You may catch this case and bypass the first line :

```
if(typeof marker!=='undefined'){
   marker.setMap(null);
}
```

But a better approach would be to use always the same marker and apply the new position:

```
function placeMarker(location) {

    //when marker is undefined, create a marker
    if(typeof marker==='undefined'){
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map
              });
    }
    //set the position
    marker.setPosition(location);


    latitude = location.lat();
    longitude = locaton.lng();

    document.getElementById('koordinaten').innerHTML 
       = '<p>' + latitude + '</p>';

}
```